# compare file 1 against file 2 and output differences from file 1 into another file called file 3 using linux

Tags: linux, file, compare

I have two files, file 1 and file 2, i need to check for the differences between the two files, and any lines that are not in file 1 i need to output to final 3.
Can anybody help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use diff tool in linux to compare two files.
like **diff file1 file2** that will give you diffrence between two files and You can also use **--changed-group-format** and **--unchanged-group-format** options to filter required data.

---

Comment: But how can i save the differences into another file?